# Insert and select within same sp?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, ado.net

Here I came up with situation where I want insert records in temp temple and again want to dispaly that record to user.

I have created one sp in that sp created temp table, added record to that table and select record from temp table.How to show record to user in interface?

`ExecuteNOnquery` is used for inserting record and `ExecuteReader` is is used for selecting record.

Withing same sp,I have insert and select.So how to do that in code behind?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ExecuteReader`.

All it does - sends string of `CommandText` to server, executes it, and then builds `SqlDataReader` to read from.

So if your `CommandText is` a call to stored procedure - this procedure will be executed (so it will insert your data and select it back) and returned data will be available in `SqlDataReader`.

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for reference to `ExecuteReader`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand("MY_SP",con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    var ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    if(ds.Tables.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach(var dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            // Do stuffs with dr
        }
    }
}
```